# Customizable table/label to make a matrix

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview, controls

I am trying to use Visual C# to make an editable row/column matrix. Essentially what I want to do is this:

[image]

The Row and Col values will be editable and i would like for the amount of cells to resize inside its bounds. That is, if i change the rows to this:

[image]

The bounds should stay the same.

What sort of Container should I begin using? I have tried a panel control with coloured labels but I can't think of how to resize them?

Comment: `DataGridView` with some of the `Auto-size` (or similarly named) properties.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Do you have an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag the `DataGridView` control from your toolbox onto your form:

[image: dgv]

I've used the following code before to distribute the column widths evenly:

```
base.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

An `AutoSizeRowsMode` property also exists.

Comment: Can i colour the rows/cols separately. How can i add and then set row size from code?

Comment: @Ben You could try `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows){ row.Height = 5; }`